# Use multiple WAN IP addresses on a single VLAN

Tags: routing, nat, pfsense

Our ISP has given us a /25 range of IP addresses on our lease line.

We want to be able to create several VLAN's and direcly assign each VLAN with any number of these WAN IP addresses.

For example -

VLAN5 needs 5 external IP addresses
VLAN2 needs 2 IP addresses

Each VLAN has a router connected to it, which we will enter the WAN IP addresses into the WAN settings of the router, rather than the VLAN local IP address.

Is this possible in pfsense and how?

Thanks

Comment: Are you happy to NAT these addresses?

Comment: Preferably not. I want the pfSense to control the bandwidth limits for each vlan and thats it. It needs to be an open gateway to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide the /25 range into /26, /27, /28, /29 or /30 ranges. Then your router would have a separate IP address in each of these networks, and would handle the routing between those subnetworks and the Internet.

Comment: So do you mean have multiple gateways set up on the pfSense?

Comment: Yes, you need to have a VLAN network interface for each network in your pfSense firewall.

Comment: OK, I will give this a try tomorrow.